# How to determine if a class was instantiated by a method in another class?

Tags: python

```
def _check_value(number):
    if not 0 <= number <= 10:
        raise ValueError
    return number


class A:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = _check_value(number)


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.factor = 2

    def my_algorithm(self, number):
        number = _check_value(number)
        number += 1 * self.factor
        return A(number)
```

The above example is a simplified version of my code. Class `A` can be instantiated directly or by the method `my_algorithm()` in class `B`. I need to check the `number` value in both cases. My problem is that when I instantiated class `A` using the method in class `B`, there will be a double checking for `number` value.

My question is how to know that class `A` was instantiated using the method in class `B` in order to avoid double checking? Or is there any better solution?

Comment: It should not matter how something was instantiated, it’s crazy that your code needs to depend on that distinction. You need to code it so it works either way.

Comment: While I agree with @deceze, if you really want to do something like this you could define in a `classmethod` in class `A` that doesn't do the checking and call that from class `B` to create new instance something like this: `return A.quick_make(number)` (assuming that was the name of the new method).

Comment: ... why don't you just not call `_check_value` in `my_algorithm`?

Comment: The idea is that `my_algorithm` needs a valid `number` to return a correct result. Then the `number` passed to class `A` will be already validated and no need to be validated again. But when class `A` is instantiated from other place, we need to validate the `number` before calling other algorithms inside class `A`. I'm thinking of may be using `__new__` method and overloading it using a subclass.

Comment: Literally answering your question, give A's `__init__()` an additional parameter `from_b=False`, saves that in an instance variable, and make B instantiate A with `from_b=true`. BUT why not simply leave the check to A especially given in your code B is modifying the `number` after checking it so A might fail it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with following code to avoid double checking:

```py
def _check_value(number):
    if not 0 <= number <= 10:
        raise ValueError
    return number


class A:
    def __init__(self, number, check=True):
        if check:
            self.number = _check_value(number)
        else:
            self.number = number


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.factor = 2

    def my_algorithm(self, number):
        number = _check_value(number)
        number += 1 * self.factor
        return A(number, check=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% following your question on instances, but I reckon you don't *have* to check the value twice? Could `try ... except` be of help here?

```
def _check_value(number):
    if not 0 <= number <= 10:
        raise ValueError
    return number


class A:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = _check_value(number)


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.factor = 2

    def my_algorithm(self, number):
        try:
            return A(number + 1 * self.factor)
        except ValueError: # not a very descriptive error, but nbd
            print("Provided value is out of bounds")
```

Comment: Appreciate it but it's not what i'm looking for.